# Error compiling giac (inside SageMath) in poly.h function

Tags: gcc, sage

Environment:
CentOS 7.9
GCC 13.1.0
SageMath 10.0

When compiling SageMath, the compilation gets to the "giac" program and fails.  The failure occurs in the "poly.h" function.  I'm on a closed network so I cannot upload the logfile.

Here is the last part of the error:

```
modpoly.cc:16082:1: internal compiler error: Aborted
16083 | } // namespace giac
      | ^
0xe017df crash signal
        ../../gcc-13.1.0/gcc/toplev.cc:314
0x7f4b842bf32d mpc_div_zero
        <path>/mpc-1.3.1/src/div/.c:31
0x7f4b842bf32d mpc_div_zero
        <path>/mpc-1.3.1/src/div/.c:259
```

There is more but it's a lot to type  :-)

Any suggestions?  Do you need to see more to assist?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Hi!  You'll get much quicker help on this kind of compile question on the Sage support Google group; it's pretty hard to debug on a Q&A type site like this one.  I didn't seen anything with this particular compile failure on a cursory search, so it could be good to email there.  Good luck!